# What type of machine learning algorithm is more suitable for predicting next destination of a ship based on previous visits?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, bayesian-networks

I'm looking at machine learning algorithms in order to investigate which category of algorithms are more appropriate for this type of problem.

**Problem**: There are history of ship voyages available (and can be used as training data), based on that we need to predict what port will be the next destination. 
I'm still not sure what type of problem this can be classified as and which algorithms are best candidates to start with (bayesian network, neural network, decision tree etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will strongly advise you hidden markov models or recurrent neural networks (like LSTMs or GRUs). These models might catch sequential regularities of your data much better than algorithms designed to deal with static (not sequential) input. I would first try to learn HMM because usually if it catches distribution needed really well, then extracting knowledge and insights from data is much easier than from RNNs. Another advantage of HMM is that it's relatively easier to design model which makes use of a prior knowledge which you have about your data. If results from HMM will not satisfy you then try RNNs. They are much more powerful when it comes to expressional power but it is a classic example of a black box model. It's hard to examine what your network had really learnt and get additional insights from data. But if what you really care is accuracy then try RNNs. They are truly powerful.

**UPDATE :**
Due to additional information which might be useful in prediction I would also advice you consider the mix of Markov models and Bayessian inference. In this case you can build your Markov model where every state represents a harbour but the probability distribution of your next transition depends not only on a harbour which you are currently visiting but also on additional information which you have. In this case the workflow is following :

1. First you try to model the dependencies between state transition and additional info by setting a family of distributions parameterized by a set of parameters `theta`.
2. After modeling phase you are trying to infer the best values of parameters by Bayessian inference and EM algorithm.

There are examples of usage of such models e.g.  [here](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/mygsb/faculty/research/pubfiles/4587/ascarza_hardie_churn.pdf&q=churn%20markov%20bayessian&ved=0ahUKEwjx9sy_8enMAhXJa5oKHf40AKwQFggvMAM&usg=AFQjCNH8CcMghpmWXhNSt-StYq8hu7t8Bw&sig2=-DkOKWd3_ccMWD_axjJzWw) but usually achieving success depends on good modeling of dependencies between current state of model and additional info.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, as I commented on Vlad's response, initial dataset has rich information about ships including port of call and date, cargo data.

Comment: How much of data do you have? What is the size of your dataset?

Comment: Size of dataset is not too big, each ship has a history of almost 1000 previous visits.

Comment: I tried HMMs but one issue I have is that HMMs assume there is only one emission variable per state whereas in my case there can be multiple possible emissions for each hidden state. Is there any variant of HMMs which could do this or I need to look into different models? (btw I looked at naive bayes classifier and a few papers which claimed they could work around this but practically didn't get to anywhere). Note: emissions can be considered independent of each other.

Comment: E.g. in HMM package in R you could have a random vector instead of single random variable as an emission.

Comment: I see there is a package ‘mhsmm’ which is possibly suitable for this. However, I was interested to look at high level implementation of such an algorithm as I have to implement that not in R but in C family languages. I found several cases where people refer to that model as MMM (multi-variant markov model), even suggesting naive bayes model and so on. Do you know of any model representing how this is implemented? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Depends what you have in your initial dataset.  If it is just a history of ports of call,  maybe building Markov chain using something like Q-learner will be your best bet.   If you have supplementary date  ( type of cargo,  seasons,  etc ) decision tree would be a good choice.  I would stay away from neural network for this type of dataset.

One thing to watch out for is that it is very easy to overfit on this type of data, so your model might just learn names of the ships and their corresponding routes given the date.   It will give you perfect results on your original sets but will be completely unable to predict future routes.

To avoid overfitting I would play with features.  Try to decompose the dates into coarser things ( like summer/ fall)  drop anything that too specific ( names of ships).

Comment: Thanks Vlad. My dataset has ports of call including dates, cargo information and some more fields.

Comment: As Marcin mentioned below HMM or even regular Markov chain might be the best bet for you.  I'd stay away from Neural Networks unless you have a lot of data to train your networks.  RNNs learn very slow.

Comment: Another reason to avoid NNs in this case is, as you say, this type of data is going to be prone to overfitting. Better to use more transparent methods (Markov or what-have-you).